# Need help properly calling a C function from Delphi

Tags: c, arrays, delphi, pointers, dll

I am statically importing a dynamic library (DLL) within Delphi and attempting to access its functions.

Here is the specific C function deceleration that I am trying to access:

```
int flann_radius_search_double (flann_index_t index_ptr, /* the index */
                                double* query, /* query point */
                                int* indices, /* array for storing the indices found (will be modified) */
                                double* dists, /* similar, but for storing distances */
                                int max_nn,  /* size of arrays indices and dists */
                                float radius, /* search radius (squared radius for euclidian metric) */
                                struct FLANNParameters* flann_params);
```

Here is my deceleration in Delphi:

```
function flann_radius_search_double(index_ptr: flann_index_t;
  var query: double; var indices: longint; var dists: double;
  max_nn: longint; radius: single; var flann_params: FLANNParameters): longint;
  cdecl; external External_library Name 'flann_radius_search_double';
```

And I accessed the function like this:

```
  type
  TDoubleArray = array[0..1000] of double;
  PDoubleArray = ^TDoubleArray;

  TIntArray = array[0..1000] of Integer;
  PIntArray = ^TIntArray;
  ...
  ... <other unrelated code>

  var      
    Indicies:TIntArray;
    PIndicies:PIntArray;
    Dists:TDoubleArray;
    PDists:PDoubleArray;
    ...
  begin
    ...
    PIndicies:=@Indicies;
    PDists   :=@Dists; 

   radius_s:=flann_radius_search_double(idx ,&PMyArray^[0,0],Pindicies^[0],&PDists^[0],1000,10,&DEFAULT_FLANN_PARAMETERS);
```

It is not working, and looks way off :*( 
I would really appreciate some assistance!

Edit: I fixed the double/single mistake, but when I attempt to use @Indicies[0] instead of Indicies[0] I get an error:

> Error: Call by var for arg no. 3 has to match exactly: Got "Pointer"
>   expected "LongInt"

Comment: You've got to change the import declaration too! Change from var indices: Integer to indices: Pinteger, like I said and like Rudy demonstrated.You've got to change the import declaration too! Change from var indices: Integer to indices: Pinteger, like I said and like Rudy demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** what is written below refers to the original version of the question before it was completely changed. In the original version the floating point parameters were all float. I would urge Mike to post the real code using copy/paste in order to avoid wasting people's time.

C float is equivalent to Delphi Single, the 4 byte floating point type. That's the main problem you have.

I personally would declare the arrays as PSingle or PInteger in the import declaration, rather than using var parameters. When passing single values by reference then var parameters is appropriate.

When calling the function I wouldn't use fixed dimensioned arrays. I would use dynamic arrays and SetLength. Pass the array then with PSingle(MyArray), or @MyArray[0], whichever you prefer.

I would prefer Integer to Longint since I believe that Integer most closely matches C int.

Your arrays are 1001 elements in size, you only need them to be 1000.

The struct is best passed by var as you have it in the import declaration, but not as you have it in the call. Since the code in your question doesn't quite match up I don't want to say anything more.

```
function flann_radius_search_double(
  index_ptr: flann_index_t;
  var query: Single;
  indices: PInteger;
  dists: PSingle;
  max_nn: Integer;
  radius: Single;
  var flann_params: FLANNParameters
): Integer; cdecl; external External_library Name 'flann_radius_search_double';   
...
var
  indices: array of Integer;
  dists: array of Single;
...
SetLength(indices, 1000);
SetLength(dists, 1000);    
radius_s := flann_radius_search_double(
  idx,
  MyArray[0,0],
  @indicies[0],
  @dists[0],
  1000,
  10.0,
  DEFAULT_FLANN_PARAMETERS
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi, `float` maps to `Single`, **not** `Double`. So it becomes:

```
function flann_radius_search_double(index_ptr: flann_index_t; 
                                    var query: Single;
                                    indices: PInteger; // array, so NOT a var parameter
                                    dists: PSingle;    // array, so NOT a var parameter 
                                    max_nn: Integer;
                                    radius: Single;
                                    var flann_params: FLANNParameters): Integer; 
   cdecl; etc...
```

You call it like:

```
 const
   CArraySize = 1000;

 ...

 var
   Indices: array[0..CArraySize - 1] of Integer;
   Dists: array[0..CArraySize - 1] of Single;
 begin
   ...
   x := flann_radius_search_double(idx, yourQuery, 
          @Indices[0], @Dists[0], Length(Dists), yourRadius, yourFlannParams);
```

Comment: There's an echo in here!! ;-)

Comment: Well, the problems with his code are the same for everyone. ;-) His way of referring to the arrays was utterly confused, so I decided to show how to do it properly. One piece of source code says more than 1000 words. ;-)

Comment: Hm, I cannot get @Indicies[0] or @Dists[0] to work like that... I get an error: Error: Call by var for arg no. 3 has to match exactly: Got "Pointer" expected "LongInt"

Comment: @rudy on the other hand, source code with no explanation doesn't teach anything, other than how to copy. Best would be a merging of these two answers.

Comment: @Mike: Did you also apply the other changes? **I guess you did not**. My translation uses **pointers**, and **not var parameters**. Var parameters are wrong when you want to pass arrays (see my conversion article). If you use my translation, then you can pass the array like I did.

Comment: @David: it is the only way to show how to pass parameters properly, instead of something like `&PDists[0,0]` or passing a constant to a var parameter. And I learned a lot by only studying other people's source code, with out without comments.